# Wait for a function to finish in JS

Tags: javascript

everyone.

I would like to know how can I make JS to wait until my function finishes, to use its retruned value.

I use to do this:

```
function printHelloWorld(){
    var x = myHolyFunction("Hello");
    console.log(x);
}

function myHolyFunction(y){
    z = y + "World";
    return z;
}
```

But my current problem is that `myHolyFunction` recieves an argument, sends it to PHP, and has to wait until PHP sends an answer. I know how to wait for PHP (helped by `.done` from ajax), but for that moment the `console.log` line (from printHello) has been executed printing `undefined`.

The point is that I'm handling so many variables in `printHelloWorld` that I couldn't simply make this:

```
function printHelloWorld(){
    var x = myHolyFunction("Hello");
    if(typeof(x) != undefined){
        console.log(x);
    }else{
        setTimeOut(printHelloWorld, 100);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

-----Follows almost sure irrelevant information----

Looking in other threads I found something about "callbacks" (I'm not a professional programmer) and I tried something like this:

```
function printHelloWorld(){
    var i = "!";
    myHolyFunction("Hello", function(j){console.log(j);});
    var k = j + i;
    console.log(k);//I would thank a "HelloWorld!" right here
}

function myHolyFunction(y, callback){
    z = y + "World";
    return callback(z);
}
```

But it doesn't solves the problem for two reasons: 1) `j` keeps inside the function and I've read that global variables are not the best option and 2)it doesn't even waits... but executes at the same time. I mean, even if I use a global variable, for the moment it gets the value from `myHolyFunction`, the line where I declare `k` would be alredy executed, printing me also "undefined".

Comment: anything you want to execute after myholyfunction will go in its callback function you have to put your k=..... in function(j)

Comment: Your function is *asynchronous* ("will finish sometime later"). It will never return synchronously. Any caller of that function must also be asynchronous and also can never return synchronously.